# unable to connect to bluemix object storage from dotnet application

Tags: ibm-cloud

We are unable to connect to `bluemix` object storage from "`DOTNET`" application using the below code.

```
 var username = "xxxx";
            var auth_url = "https://cos-service.bluemix.net/endpoints";

            var identity = new CloudIdentity()
            {
                Username = username,
                APIKey = "xxxxx"
            };

            var identityProvider = new OpenStackIdentityProvider(new Uri(auth_url));
            var conn = new CloudServersProvider(identity, identityProvider);

            CloudFilesProvider cfp = new CloudFilesProvider(identity);
            var containers = cfp.ListContainers();
```

We are getting error :

> "Unable to authenticate user and retrieve authorized service
>   endpoints"

.

Thanks,
Praveen

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using IBM Cloud Object Storage which uses a slightly modified version of AWS S3 API and not the Swift API.

You can try creating a hmac credentials:

[image]

Source: https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/cloud-object-storage/iam/service-credentials.html#service-credentials

You can then use the [aws s3 library](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSdkDocsNET/latest/V3/DeveloperGuide/welcome.html) providing the hmac credentials.  Ensure you override the endpoint to point to your cos instance - [example](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/overriding-endpoints-in-the-aws-sdk-for-net/)

If you are using python, java or nodejs, IBM provide a library that you can use that does not require the special hmac credentials.